# SQL Sever (2008) Connection with PHP via Virtual Machine and Mac in same computer

Tags: php, sql-server, virtual-machine

So, I have a database in my virtual machine (VMware Fusion) windows based, and I want to program in php on my mac. How do i establish the connection to use the database from my virtual machine to my php on my mac.

-this is all on the same computer
-virtual machine is VMware Fusion 5
-VM is Windows based
-DB is on SQL Server 2008 management
-I will program on my mac with php

Comment: Are you required to use SQL Server? This sounds like a lot of work when you could be running a similar setup on the Mac side... _(or simply purchase a separate Windows machine, for that matter... right tool, right job?)_

Comment: Yes, its for a class. I mean, I'm sure its possible, but just how?